# Using files and queues in php

Tags: php, file

Here in this code i had used files to store the numbers by appending them separated by coma and performed array operations.But I had to store only first 6 numbers in file and the number entered from 7th time onwards should be added last to file and delete out the first number in file i.e just like push and pop.How can i do that?

```
<?php 
$number=$_POST['number'];
if(isset($_POST['number'])) 
{
  $data = $_POST['number'] . ",";
  file_put_contents('data_file.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
$text = file_get_contents('data_file.txt');
$a1 = explode(',',$text);
$k=count($a1);
$i=$k-1;
if($i== 1)
{
  echo "Hi User your Lucky number Wins,CONGRATS!!!". "<br><br>";
  echo "Your Number :" .$a1[0]. "<br><br>";  
}
elseif(($i>1) && ($i<=5))
{
  if($a1[$i-1]==$a1[$i-2])
   {
     echo "Hi User your Lucky number Wins,CONGRATS!!!" ."<br><br>";
     echo "Your Number :" .$a1[$i-1]. "<br><br>"; 
   }
  else 
  {
    echo "Hey User you lose!!!SORRY!!!" . "<br><br>";
    echo "Your Number :" .$a1[$i-1]. "<br><br>"; 
  }
}
elseif($i>=6)
{
  $sum=0;
  for($j=$i-1;$j>$i-6;$j--)
   {
     $sum=$sum + $a1[$j-1];
   }
   echo "Sum is : $sum";
   echo "<br><br>";
   $average = $sum/5;
   echo "Average is : $average";
   echo "<br><br>";
   $result2=round($average);
   if($result2==$number)
    {
      echo "Hi User your Lucky number Wins,CONGRATS!!!" ."<br><br>";
      echo "Your Number :" .$number. "<br><br>"; 

    }
   else 
    {
      echo "Hey User you lose!!!SORRY!!!".  "<br><br>";
      echo "Your Number :" .$number. "<br><br>"; 
     }
 }
else
{
  echo "error";
}
?>
```

Comment: revise your question please, because I cannot grasp what you are asking

Comment: @Edwin may be you can get it now

Comment: so you want to have always 6 numbers inside? for that just make sure that your output array has always max 6 values and then just use `file_put_contents`. And you should think about refactoring your code, because this is a no-go code.